# What is time complexity to print char array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, cout

So I was trying a basic program to print prefix substrings of String (substrings "","a","ab","abc" for string "abc") and its working fine:

```
void PrefixSubstrings(string s, int n){
cout<<"sub = "<<endl; // assumes empty subst as subst as well 
char sub[n+1];
for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
    sub[j]= s[j] ; 
    sub[j+1]=0 ;
    cout<<"sub = "<<sub<<endl;
}}
```

But then I thought about its Time Complexity , it might seem O(n) ,but then I noticed for the part

cout<<"sub = "<<sub<<endl;

I am not sure but does it taking extra O(n) to print char array using above method and making my program effectively O(n^2) ?

Comment: `char sub[n+1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  Instead: `std::vector<char> sub(n+1);`

Comment: Yes, its complexity would be quadratic on the length of the string.

Comment: @WaisKamal I searched over the net but couldn't find a way to print char array in constant time . So if I use string instead of char to store substrings and print , would that be in constant time? Or is there any other way to print it in constant time ?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be possible to take the same amount of time to print a string no matter how many characters are in it?

Comment: How can you print n characters in constant time? This would mean skipping some characters. Even if you use a string, it will print one character at a time behind the scenes.

Comment: You print `6 + (6+1) + (6+2) + ... + (6 + n) = 6 + 6* n + (1+2+...+n) = 6 + 6*n + n * (n+1) / 2` chars in total (plus another O(n) line breaks); the complexity is clearly quadratic...

Comment: I concur , but I had doubt because since I have seen many code posts and articles ignoring the time complexity to print char array / string .

Comment: Were they assessing the time complexity of an algorithm with respect to the number of characters? For a lot of algorithms "number of characters" isn't the main independent variable that you would use for complexity analysis. But without seeing the code posts and articles you're thinking of, it's hard to say if this is a particularly relevant omission or not.

Comment: Ya I think they didn't put value to consider time complexity of char print 
, anyways @NathanPierson my one of references of article was with the method 5 on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-print-substrings-given-string/

Comment: That article says the time complexity is `O(N²)`, so it seems like it agrees with you.